# 12 Factor Apps - Run admin/management tasks as one-off processes

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

Is it possible to explain the below and why it is not supported by PCF?

> **Admin Processes**
>
> Run admin/management tasks as one-off processes. This is not currently supported by PCF, so applications and
>   application suites that require this functionality need to be examined
>   more closely for replatforming suitability.

Comment: Where does that quoted text come from?

Comment: It comes from a document that I received from pivotal cloud foundry about couple of years ago.

Comment: So ... how do you know if it isn't (up to two years) out of date?  I can't find anything like that statement in a Google search!

Comment: Yes , I tried searching too , but wasn’t able to find . Just wanted to check if someone can help me understand what is meant by admin process , why it wasn’t supported by pcf and if it is supported now

Comment: I think you would be better off asking Pivotal directly.  They have a support site ... even a 1-800 number.  Talk to them: they won't bite you!

Comment: I got it as part of training but don’t have any contact within that organization at the moment. But sure will try to see if anyone else that i know has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at running tasks on Cloudfoundry: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html

So yes, this is supported.

Comment: Thank you , this answers